# How can I set the channel of a Parse.Installation through cloud code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

According to the push [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#setup/JavaScript), this doesn't seem to be supported yet, but I'm not entirely sure. I have a background job that's running for every user in the database, and I want it to set their respective installations channel based on the result.